# Como encontrar el numero de concurrencias en una matriz

Tags: java

### Tengo que encontrar el numero de coincidencias ya sea 4 o mas continua o oblicua

Tengo que mandar un arreglo a un método y este método recibe un  arreglo(EL ARREGLO QUE MANDO)
Lo que intento hacer es que recibo ese arreglo y después lo tengo que convertir en una matriz para poder buscar por filas y columnas
Pero al querer convertirlo me sale como un arreglo normal O sea todo seguido y no como una matriz.
y debido a esto mi condición ala hora de  validar la fila me entra por que valida todo el arreglo y encuentra mas de 4 coincidencias.

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
String[] dna = new String[] {"ATCGGA","CAGTGC","TGACAT","TGACGG"
        + "GCGTCA","TCACTG"};
 hasMutation(dna);
}

static  boolean hasMutation(String[] dna)
{
   int a = 6;
   int b = 6;
   char Matriz[][] = new char[a][b];
   String texto = "";

   for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
   {
      texto = dna[i];

      for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
      {
         Matriz[i][j] = texto.charAt(j);
         System.out.print(Matriz[i][j]); //Imprimo la matriz ya transformada SEGUN YO
         for (int t = 0; t < Matriz.length; t++) {
                
                for (int p = 0; p < Matriz[0].length; p++) {

                if (Matriz[t][p] == Matriz[t][p+1] 
                     && Matriz[t][p] == Matriz[t][p+2] 
                     && Matriz[t][p] == Matriz[t][p+3])
                        {
                         
                        System.out.print("Con mutacion");
            
                        }
                }
            }
         
      }
   }
   

   
   return false;
}
```

ATCGGACAGTGCTGACATTGACGGTCACTG ala hora de querer de imprimir mi matriz

Comment: Pq eliminaste tu otra pregunta, respeta mi tiempo eso no se hace

Answer (score 0):

La razón es que al hacer uso de `print()` estas concatenando los valores de la matriz que creaste ,es por eso que te imprime los valores como una cadena o como un arreglo, faltaría el uso de un `println()` después del segundo `for` para obtener la impresión deseada podrías dividir tu código entre convertir tu arreglo en matriz y otra que recibe como parámetro esa matriz para aplicar tu método `hashMutation`

```
static char [][] cambiarMatriz(String[] dna){
   int a = 6;
   int b = 6;
   char matriz[][] = new char[a][b];
   String texto = "";

   for (int i = 0; i < a; i++){
      texto = dna[i];
      for (int j = 0; j < b; j++){
         matriz[i][j] = texto.charAt(j);
       }
   }
   return matriz;
}
```

en el `main` obtienes tu matriz,y la imprimes agregando el salto de linea que te hacia falta, y aplicas tu otro método con la matriz obtenida

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
String[] dna = new String[] {"ATCGGA","CAGTGC","TGACAT","TGACGG","GCGTCA","TCACTG"};

char[][]matriz=cambiarMatriz(dna);

for (int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++ ) {
    for (int j=0;j<matriz[i].length;j++ ) {
        System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

System.out.println(hasMutation(matriz));

    }

}
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la condicion estricta es que el metodo hasMutation reciba un arreglo no una matriz por eso lo puse asi.

Comment: y despues ese metodo busca las coincidencias y devuleve un true o false